# How to fix error MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute'

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, .net-core

I had a WPF project. For reporting service i am using

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms &

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms.

Everything working when it was running on .Net framework 4.7.2.

Now i ported it to .Net Core 3.0 and now i am facing this error.

Error MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute' in assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\System.Web.dll'.'    My Shop WPF C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets   225

How i can resolve this issue ?

Comment: The core library does not support all the Net library classes/methods.  See : https://tomasherceg.com/blog/post/migrating-asp-net-web-forms-apps-to-net-core-using-dotvvm

Answer (score 0):

The core library does not support all the Net library classes/methods.
We have to create another project in .NET Framework and use Microsoft.ReportingServices in .NET Framework project.

Now add .Net Framework project to .Net core app

Comment: Did it work? I got this error when referencing a .net 4.7.2 Framework project ...