# Could not find type 'System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute' after migrating to .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core

I used upgrade-assistant (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/upgrade-assistant/) to migrate a .NET Framework 4.5.2 class library to .NET 5.0 and am 3 days into trying to fix a subsequent build error:

*C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(240,9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute' in assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Web.dll'.'  [redacted.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)*

Double-clicking on the error in Visual Studio takes me to this location in Microsoft.WinFX.Targets file:
[image: Visual Studio 2019 Error Location]

According to the Microsoft Documentation, "The MarkupCompilePass1 task converts non-localizable XAML project files to compiled binary format". The class library contains both WinForms and WPF Controls. This implies a problem with one (or more) of the WPF Controls, but there are no explicit instances of "TagPrefixAttribute" in the code, so I'm confused. TagPrefixAttribute "defines the tag prefix used in a Web page to identify custom controls." - the DLL is referenced by Windows desktop apps (nothing to do with web).

I created a binary log and examined it with the MSBuild Structured Log Viewer, but didn't gain any more information (I'm a long time user of MSBuild, but fortunately/unfortunately have never had to dig into the guts at this level, so maybe I'm not looking at the right spot):

[image: MSBuild Structured Log Viewer]

The only other instance of this error on StackOverflow is this question:

[How to fix error MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512973/how-to-fix-error-mc1000unknown-build-error-could-not-find-type-system-web-ui)

And that person was referencing a specific DLL that was causing the problem so the resolution was obvious.

I've been putting off this much-needed push to .NET Core from NetFx and would love anybody long time if they can shed some insight into this problem!

Comment: Hi, @Shea. 
For [System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.tagprefixattribute?view=netframework-4.8) Class, it is applicable to .NET Framework 1.1-4.8 version. Are you directly referencing System.Web in your WPF project? If so, you could try to remove this dependency before migrating. Are there any third-party components in your project before migrating?

Comment: Hi, @HuiLiu-MFST. I am not directly referencing System.Web in my WPF project. I am referencing assemblies from a 3rd party that reference System.Web, could this transitive dependency cause the build error? This would surprise me because I converted another WPF/WinForms class library to .NET 5 which references one of the 3rd party class libraries that reference System.Web and it compiles & runs okay. My thinking/hope was that I would see a runtime error if anything tried to use System.Web, but it would be okay otherwise. (The goal is to eventaully remove this 3rd party component).

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST - correction to my above comment. I believe the problem is due to the transitive dependency on System.Web. I was mistaken that another converted WPF/WinForms class library with transitive dependency on System.Web compiled - I had removed that dependency. The build error indicating an issue with MarkupCompilePass1 is misleading. I am going to try and factor the offending dependency into another class library and will report back.

Comment: Hi, @Shea. Are there any new developments in the problem? There may be item does not create the correct structure for the project. Either the third party, studio, nuget packages/manager. You could also try to manually restructured the project file to their correct target frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message.   I removed all DevExpress Dll's and added only those back which gave an error when compiling.  As a result, some DevExpress DLL's were removed and the project compiled without the "unknown build error".

Comment: Can you be more specific about which DLLs needed removal?